# How to trim a string without additional memory allocations in C#?

Tags: c#, string, .net-core, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a string `input`. I want to remove the last symbol from it. I can do it in this way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "Hello World-";
    string result = input.TrimEnd('-');
    Console.WriteLine(result); // Hello World
}
```

It works, but `TrimEnd()` calls `System.String.FastAllocateString()` internally. It makes sense, because `string` is immutable data structure, and in common case we cannot do anything else. However, in my case I don't need `input` anymore, so I would like to reuse its internal buffer, rather than allocate additional buffer, and "ask" `GC` to clean `input` buffer eventually. It could reduce overall allocations, and reduce GC work.

Comment: I get your line of thinking, but I guess it doesn't exactly work that way. _BUT_: do really need a `string` going forward or can you use a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`?

Comment: @Fildor well, `ReadOnlySpan<char>` could work in general, but for my specific case it will require to refactor a lot, because consumers expect to have a `string`.

Comment: ReadOnlySpan has a ToString() method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ReadOnlySpan.ToString allocates memory.

Comment: Have you measured the performance of your code and determined whether or not you actually have a performance problem?  This is premature optimization otherwise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey a few difference ways, but one of them is allocation profile in Perfview.

Comment: OK, but does it matter?  Do your software requirements state a performance specification that you cannot achieve because your string allocations are taking too long?

Comment: @RobertHarvey so, at the moment, my software has problems with tail latency at P95, and the main reason is GC contribution. Now, I try to eliminate allocations to improve tail latency.

Comment: [StringPool?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/high-performance/stringpool)

Comment: Thanks for sharing StringPool, I wasn't aware about such library, but I was thinking to code something similar. From the first glance, it shouldn't help me, because as I can see, the library uses hash-based maps, so it will work for cases, when we have a lot of similar strings. My case is a bit different, `input` is a just random string. Anyway, I will try to analyze it further, thanks!

Comment: If your biggest overhead is specifically GC for *strings*, it sounds like you seriously need to refactor your code base and *make it less string obsessed*. If it "needs" to be string obsessed, you've already been pointed out the modern low allocation methods but you need to switch to using *those* instead of insisting everything stays as `string` and you'll instead attempt to subvert standard and expected invariants.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yea, I completely agree with you. I just wanted to double check with SO people, do I have any other shortcut, before starting refactoring codebase, removing direct `string` usage.

Answer (score 3):

`Console.Out.WriteLine` does not accept a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` as input, but `Console.Out`, which is a `TextWriter`, does expose such a method. Therefore, the correct way to avoid allocations is:

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<char> input = "Hello World-";
Console.Out.WriteLine(input.TrimEnd('-'));

// or

// Uses an indexer to always remove the last character:
Console.Out.WriteLine(input[..^1]);
```

---

If you need a string as result and you have to apply several string operations on the input, then using a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` will save you repeated allocations on the intermediate results, but in the end you will have to allocate a new string and the possible string operations are very limited. Unless you are willing to use unsafe code or to make a detour via COM code, there is no way to break this rule.

Alternatively, you can use a `StringBuilder` for string manipulations. But this will allocate a `char[]` buffer and `ToString` calls `FastAllocateString` as well. See [Reference Source for `StringBuilder`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs).

Comment: Sorry, I used `Console.WriteLine` just to show needed result. I need to get `string` as a result, not print it.

Answer (score -1):

This is what the `ReadOnlySpan` struct & `System.Memory` namespace are for

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<char> input = "Hello World-";
string result = new string(input.TrimEnd('-'));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: you allocate memory in your example, so it is not what I want to have :(

Comment: The allocation is only on the final result. The span allocation will be on the stack

Comment: that's true for your example, but I have already had `input` as a `string`, so it would be the second allocation.